# Token based authentication by Angular and Web API – 404 error

Tags: sql, angular, asp.net-web-api

I  am working  with Angular and ASP.NET Web API. When I try token based authentication and send login request, I'm getting the following error: `POST http://localhost:53339/token 404 (Not Found)`

I  have tried  multiple solutions.

**webapi startup class:**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    ConfigureOAuth(app);
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}

public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll); //For support cross region
    var testProvider = new Providers.MyAuthorizeProvider();
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14.0),
        AuthorizationCodeExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14.0),
        RefreshTokenProvider = new Providers.RefreshTokenProvider(),
        Provider = testProvider ,
    };
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
}
```

I want token based authentication by Angular and Web API.

---

When i try to call api its show this 404 eror local host not found

```
<rewrite> 
  <rules> 
    <rule name="RewriteRules" stopProcessing="true"> 
      <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" /> 
      </conditions> 
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" /> 
    </rule> 
  </rules> 
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Have you verified that your ConfigureOAuth() method is being called? Are you using any type of URL rewriting?

Comment: When i try to call api its show this 404 eror local host not found

Comment: Understood, however that does not answer the questions I have asked.

Comment: <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteRules" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using URL rewriting rules, you will need to add an exception for your token endpoint (`/token`). Here is an example:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteRules" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <!-- EXISTING RULES -->
                <!-- Add this rule: -->
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/token" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteRules" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite> still http://localhost:53339/token 404 (Not Found)

Comment: when i try from postman  to check api throw error resource not  found

Comment: You just pasted the exact same rewrite rules you already had. Did you add the additional rule for `/token`?